# Front end file upload returning wrong attachment url

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

So I'm making a simple file uploader with wordpress where users don't need to go into wp-admin to add a file.

I have it working great, it uploads the file to the correct folder..etc but the only problem I'm running into is its returning the wrong file url.

For example when uploading a file it goes to '/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/file.png' but it returns the attachment URL as '/uploads/file.png'

My code:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-load.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-admin/includes/media.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-admin/includes/file.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-admin/includes/image.php');

 if(!$_FILES) exit;
 if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

//define variables
 if(isset($_FILES['fileUpload'])) 
     {
     $files = $_FILES['fileUpload'];
     }
 $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

 $file_name = $files['name'];
 $file_vars = array('test_form' => FALSE); //Allows form submission
 $file_post = wp_handle_upload($files, $file_vars); //Posts File
 $file_link = $file_post['url']; //Full URL
 $file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($file_link), null); //File Extension

 $post_name = preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file_link)); //Post Name

 $attachment = array(
            'guid' => $file_link, 
            'post_mime_type' => $file_type['type'],
            'post_title' => $post_name,
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
                );
 $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_name);
 //Generates meta
 $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file_name);
 //Updates meta
 $attach_final = wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to see the content of the var before the preg_replace and after maybe is that.

Answer (score 0):

**I've figured out what I was doing wrong!**

Basically when generating attachment metadata I was giving it the wrong path..

I was giving it the path of the actual file **'/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/file.png'**

but really it needed the path of the folder the file was in **'/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/'**